# Field properties in ... required a bean of type ... that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, component-scan

I have the following project structure:
[image]

**ApplicationConfiguration:**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"configuration", "nsd"})  //<- base packages here
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
}
```

**ApplicationProperties**:

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class ApplicationProperties {
 ...
```

**MyRestController**:

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {  
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationProperties properties;  // <-- could not autowire
    ...
```

When I start application I see:

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field properties in nsd.MyRestController required a bean of type
>   'configuration.ApplicationProperties' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'configuration.ApplicationProperties'
>   in your configuration.

I don't understand why. ComponentScan provided in confuguration class.

How to fix this problem?

### Update

If move ApplicationProperties to `nsd` package - context up correctly but I still don't understand why doesn't it work from old package